# Shortcode question.... javascript

Tags: shortcode

We want to create a short-code. The final output of the source code should be similar to the code mentioned below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hosted.musesradioplayer.com/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'http://streams.museter.com:8002/;',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':65,
'autoplay':true,
'buffering':5,
'title':'Radio%20Vermont',
'welcome':'WELCOME TO...',
'bgcolor':'#FFFFFF',
'skin':'mcclean',
'width':180,
'height':60
});
</script>
```

the above mentioned code, when ever we insert shortcode, url and codec variable will change...

we try with the following shortcode but its wrong... kindly help me...

```
<?
function playermp3($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "value" => 'http://',
        "width" => '180',
        "height" => '60',
        "codec"=> 'mp3',
        "volume" => '65',
        "autoplay"=>'true',
        "buffering"=> '5',
        "title"=> 'Radio%20Vermont',
        "welcome" => 'WELCOME TO...',
        "bgcolor"=>'#FFFFFF',
        "skin"=> 'mcclean',
    ), $atts));
    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hosted.musesradioplayer.com/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'.$value.',
'codec':'.$codec.',
'volume':'.$volume.',
'autoplay':'.$autoplay.',
'buffering':'.$buffering.',
'title':'.$title.',
'welcome':'.$welcome.',
'bgcolor':'.$bgcolor.',
'skin':'.$skin.',
'width':'.$height.',
'height':'.$width.'
});
</script>';
}
add_shortcode("playermp3", "playermp3");

?>
```

Comment: How exactly URL and codec value change? _Just_ them change? Also from code highlight your string opening/closing looks like it has issues.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress offers a function called [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). That function is your best friend for situations like yours. There are plenty of examples here. But I leave you with this good tutorial:

http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/

Answer (score 0):

Change your part with this one and it should work just fine:

```
"url":".$value.",
"codec":".$codec.",
"volume":".$volume.",
"autoplay":".$autoplay.",
"buffering":".$buffering.",
"title":".$title.",
"welcome":".$welcome.",
"bgcolor":".$bgcolor.",
"skin":".$skin.",
"width":".$height.",
"height":".$width."
```

If you use apostrophe for return, then make sure to use quotation marks for the data inside. Or you can do the opposite.